# induces a shudder of disbelief in some areas

Tags: meaning-in-context

Does

"The idea of Carl André’s bricks still induces a shudder of disbelief in some areas of the British press."

mean

"The idea of Carl André’s bricks still makes people not to trust some areas of the British press"?

and does any one know why this series of brick artworks by Carl André should bring about such a thing?

Art and Science by Sian Ede

Comment: Grammatically the sentence is ambiguous, since _disbelief in X_ could mean either that the disbelief occurs in X or the disbelief is about X. Probably the surrounding context clears this up.

Answer (score 1):

No, you haven't quite got it.

The sentence means that some people within the British press have a negative reaction to Carl André's artwork. They shudder when they think about it, because they can't believe somebody would try to pass off a pile of bricks as artwork.

Click [here](http://www.independent.co.uk/voices/comment/is-andres-bricks-a-pile-of-old-bricks-or-a-magnificent-piece-of-art-we-still-cant-decide-8477668.html) for an example of a person within the British press who has such a reaction.

Comment: Of course, the "shudder" may be figurative.

Answer (score 1):

No, it means that the journalists shudder.

> Equivalent VIII by Carl Andre was bought by Tate in 1972 and featured
>   in special displays in 1974 and 1975 without attracting much
>   publicity. But on 15 February 1976 an article appeared in The Sunday
>   Times about recent additions to the Tate's Collection, illustrated
>   with a picture of Equivalent VIII. The sculpture, 120 firebricks
>   arranged in a rectangular formation, an important Minimalist work,
>   provoked uproar.
>
> Press and public joined in a lively, and for the most part critical,
>   debate about The Bricks , as the work became popularly known.
>
> > http://www2.tate.org.uk/archivejourneys/historyhtml/people_public.htm

I am not sure why the press should shudder. The bricks were an excellent source of copy at the time.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently the author thinks that the some areas of the British press are "better art critics", from which "rigorous criticism [has emerged]".

The author seems to share the view of these "better art critics", that this work represents "all that is flashy, childishly provocative and calculatingly commercial".

However, they do not fail to mention that "from the outside, the art word appears to be smug and knowing, refusing to engage in a discriminating exchange of views, lest too much analysis should devalue the product."

---

These 'shudders of disbelief' are performed only by those who think they have right to condescend that a pile of bricks is *not* art. IMO, art is anything that someone will pay more than its scrap value for.

(I'd have to read the whole book to know which side of the fence the author is really on. It's also quite possible they were only being objective; merely trying to point out how holier-than-thou art critics can be.)

<sub>Art and Science by Sian Ede –[Google Books](https://books.google.com/books?id=iiE3RsvK248C&pg=PA39&lpg=PA39&dq=Art%20and%20Science%20by%20Sian%20Ede%20shudder%20of%20disbelief&source=bl&ots=Cu2YndIgu5&sig=u8MtBqJlDpA-unhiH_0wmc2tKLA&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CCQQ6AEwAWoVChMIn_eElMjExwIVxRc-Ch347gVw#v=onepage&q=Art%20and%20Science%20by%20Sian%20Ede%20shudder%20of%20disbelief&f=true)</sub>

---

If I had wrote it, it would mean:

> "The idea of Carl André’s bricks still <strike>induces a shudder of disbelief in some areas of the British press</strike> [makes some of the hoity-toity British press cringe]."

---

*Is Andre’s ‘Bricks’ a pile of old bricks or a magnificent piece of art? We still can’t decide. The 1970s row over whether ‘Bricks’ is art lingers on*, by Rosie Millard –[independent.co.uk](http://www.independent.co.uk/voices/comment/is-andres-bricks-a-pile-of-old-bricks-or-a-magnificent-piece-of-art-we-still-cant-decide-8477668.html)

[image]